# How can I summarize a table in PowerBI with single entries and multiple rows / branch data

Tags: excel, powerbi

I have a report that is made in excel like this:

[image: this]

In the database, I have 3 tables. One table is the details of the contract details, another being the multiple lengths to that contract, and a table detailing the container details to that contract. In PowerBI, I imported these tables and have set up a one-to-many relationship from the main contract table to the length and container tables. I want to reproduce the report and at the moment, I can only get it to look like this

[image: this]

without having to make multiple tables which I'm trying to avoid. Is there an addon visual or a way I can display the data such as in the first photo in PowerBI?

Comment: I think the "**matrix visual**" is what you're looking for!! Are you looking for a visual similar to Pivot Table in excel?

Answer (score 1):

In short, no.

Power BI is not designed to handle complex formatting in a single visual like you have in your example.

This *can* be achieved with the Power BI [Report Builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/report-builder-power-bi) instead, though it'll be a good bit of work.

Comment: Thank you. I'll play around with the report builder and see what I can do.